# Launch the same program several times with delay using bash

Tags: shell, server, client, sleep

I am writing a bash script to test my multi-connection TCP server. The script is supposed to launch the client several times.  Here is what I have done so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

toport=8601
for ((port = 8600; port < 8610; port++));
do
        client 10.xml &
        replace $port $toport -- "10.xml" #modifying the port in the xml file
        ((toport=toport+1))
done
```

As it is going too fast, most of the clients don't have enough time to connect to the server.  So I added `sleep 1` in the loop, as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

toport=8601
for ((port = 8600; port < 8610; port++));
do
        client 10.xml &
        replace $port $toport -- "10.xml" #modifying the port in the xml file
        ((toport=toport+1)) 
        sleep 1

done
```

But for some reason it gets even worse, since no clients are able to connect to the server anymore. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Remove the `#` from `#sleep 1`.

Comment: @agc No, I added `#` because it did not work. I am going to edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script you are running the client in background and putting the sleep statement at the end of the loop modify it like below or run your client in foreground instead of back ground

```
    client 10.xml &
    sleep 3
    replace $port $toport -- "10.xml" #modifying the port in the xml file
    ((toport=toport+1))
    #sleep 1
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! :) But, before accepting the answer, can I ask you to explain why it worked that way? How did the sleep work where you placed it, and not where I placed it?

Comment: I am putting it immediately after you run the job at the background and after that you are executing two statement related to your job. So it will work only when you put the sleep immediately after the job runs in background. That also make sure that job is running at the back ground.